# Disabled dropdown menu items using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use markup to display a dropdown menu using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1...</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 2...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to make menu items appear disabled, i.e. no hover effect and probably a different text decoration to make the disabled state visible to the user.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there an exisisting bootstrap css class I can add to the `<li>` or `<a>` element?

Comment: You want the link to "appear" disabled but not actually disabled?

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I want one or more menu items to be disabled (in every way, not only appearance).

Comment: And how are you expecting the events to take place, e.g. you want the buttons to become enabled if a certain action is taken? Or you're just looking for a way to easily disable the links with some jQuery? You can't fully disable a link with plain css.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is done using jQuery or css.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can attach a custom disabled class to your menu link `a` tag that you want to disable and simply remove the default action by using [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and targetting that class, like so:

```
$(".disabled-link").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can style all events from the `.disabled-link` with a grey backdrop or any style you like;

**CSS**

```
a.disabled-link,
a.disabled-link:visited ,
a.disabled-link:active,
a.disabled-link:hover {
    background-color:#d9d9d9 !important;
    color:#aaa !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fABRr/)

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed. I did some googling and found out about the ``pointer-events`` css attribute. This updated version of your jsfiddle uses pointer-events instead of using script to disable the action: http://jsfiddle.net/fABRr/2/

Comment: Sadly that is only supported by FF4+ and Chrome (last time i checked) :( , thought about using the same as well but did not think it was a proper answer with such lack of support.

Comment: [Support Chart](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events), no IE support (no surprise there), FF is supported ver 3.6+, no Opera support, Chrome ver 16+ support. Not bad, but not so good either :(

Comment: Ouch. I guess I'll check for the ``disabled-link`` class in the click handlers for the menu items then.

Comment: When combining bootstrap with some frameworks (eg. knockout), preventing the click event may not work. This is for example the case using knockout's `data-bind="click: ..."` . Using `.unbind("click");` instead will do the trick.

Comment: To disable the click event when using Knockout you can use the "enable" binding. No click event will fire when enable is false.

Answer (score 79):

When outputing the code for a disabled drop down, why not simply use :

```
<li class='disabled'>
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
```

You can always add the caret back if you still want it to appear.

Update:
Adding [W3Schools Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-active&stacked=h)

Comment: +1 The documentation shows you this http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs (under "Disabled state")

Comment: Also from the documentation, if you don't want links to be clickable then get rid of the `href`. Although retain the `a` for formatting.

Comment: Good answer. The only thing I don't like about this is that Bootstrap allows the dropdown to close when the user clicks on the disabled item. Hm...

Comment: When I tried this, the link "looked" disabled, but it could still be clicked on and used for navigation

Comment: This is a great bootstrap style, but it has one problem, it doesn't actually stop the item from being clicked.  @buzzy answer below takes care of this.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this (LESS):

```
/* Disable link */
a.disabled, 
a.disabled:visited ,
a.disabled:active,
a.disabled:hover {  
  color: #999 ;
  cursor: default;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  a.disabled, 
  a.disabled:visited ,
  a.disabled:active,
  a.disabled:hover {  
    color: #999 ;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To disable the the dropdown use:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('disabled');
```

To enable it back:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't add/remove after the initial page load.

Comment: it looks disabled but is still clickable. I've added `.dropdown-item.disabled {pointer-events: none;}` as mentioned in comments here

Answer (score 6):

YES, Bootstrap has a predefined class with all necessary styling you need. You can simply add **disabled** class to whichever `<li>` you want

Comment: This does not actually work, at least with Bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: Oh waid, you said for `<li>` - that works. Make sure you don't add it for `<a>`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Andres answer (don't have enough reputation to add comments :( ). You need to return false from the event handler or it might continue executing other handlers.

```
$(".disabled-link").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I believe ``event.preventDefault()`` takes care of that.

Comment: @codeape I believe that `return false` is needed for IE though.

Comment: @codeape In Chrome, return false is mandatory as well, so I would say it can be considered a good practice.

Comment: In a jQuery event handler, `return false` does two things: `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`. (When not using jQuery, [`return false` in event handlers means other things depending on where you use it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html)...) So if you add `return false`, you can remove `event.preventDefault()`, because that will be done anyway.

Comment: If you add `return false;` do not disappear the dropdown if it triggers a confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above you can use:

```
    li.disabled > a {
    color:#aaa !important;
    }
```

This way you are keeping the same bootstrap default class for disabled links and implement the  preventDefault() Javascript to disabled the link.

```
$(".disabled").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Regular link</a>
  **<a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Disabled link</a>**
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
</div>
```

Add `.disabled` to items in the dropdown to style them as disabled.
Source: [www.getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com)